# Preview doc, docx, pdf, xlxs files using php

Tags: php

I have files on server, I want users to only preview them and not read
the whole file. How do i do that using PHP?

```
$file = $_POST['prefile'];
$header="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file;"; // Send File Name
header($header);
readfile('files/'.$file);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "preview" them? Only display the beginning of the file? Something else?

Comment: Yes, Only display the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a preview of these files, saving them and displaying them first could be an option.

And that would also prevent the system to generate these files every time they were displayed, so then you would have to fit a logic to show or not the preview depending on the case.

From what I remember, some other systems apply a similar behavior when dealing with pictures. They have the full picture and at the same time, save plenty of different sizes of it for displaying.